# Post Comments using WP REST API v2 in WordPress

Tags: comments

I am using an AngularJS application with WordPress backend. I am able to retrieve comments using WP REST API v2., using the following url

/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=1324

But is there a way to post comments in WP REST API v2. I was unable to find anything in documentation. Thanks.

Comment: In the [documentation there is a section titled "Create a comment"](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/comments/). You can start there and come back if you have problems to use it.

Comment: The REST endpoint for comments is inconsistent in that the schema for content is different on the outgoing (GET side) vs. incoming (POST/PUT). When you read you get an object with raw/rendered properties. When you add/update a comment you are expected to provide a plain string for the content.

Answer (score 5):

Similar problem, I was getting back:

```
{"code":"rest_comment_login_required","message":"Sorry, you must be logged in to comment.","data":{"status":401}}
```

Looking for that code '*rest_comment_login_required*' this is one of the first results: [WP_REST_Comments_Controller::create_item_permissions_check](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_comments_controller/create_item_permissions_check/).

So from v4.7.0 there is a filter called '**rest_allow_anonymous_comments**' returning false by default. So you cannot comment by default even though your Wordpress settings indicate otherwise.

You can turn it back on by adding:

```
function filter_rest_allow_anonymous_comments() {
    return true;
}
add_filter('rest_allow_anonymous_comments','filter_rest_allow_anonymous_comments');
```

Comment: You can also use the [`__return_true`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_return_true) callback

Comment: The code provided doesn't work above, you've got the filter and callback the wrong way round :-) https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/. This is the correct code... function filter_rest_allow_anonymous_comments() {
    return true;
}
add_filter('rest_allow_anonymous_comments', 'filter_rest_allow_anonymous_comments');

Comment: You're right: I've updated the code.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the comment docs - http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/comments/

And the following syntax:

`https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?author=Your%20Name%20Here&author_email=your-email-address@website-address-here.com&author_name=Your%20Name%20Here&content=Your%20Comment%20Here&post=1604252`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://www.contradodigital.com/2016/04/06/post-comments-wordpress-rest-api-version-2/

Just had to do this myself, the documentation in the official WordPress API v2 isn't the best at the minute.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.