# Trouble Commenting via the WP REST API using nonces

Tags: rest-api

I'm trying to post a comment via the WP REST API. Here is my request:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${WP_API_ENDPOINT}/comments`,
    headers: {'X-WP-Nonce': wpRestSettings.nonce},
    data: {
        "post": 8911,
        "author_name": "Mr. Author",
        "author_email": "email@example.com",
        "content": "A new comment."
    }
})
```

I've also tried adding the nonce in the data instead under the value `_wpnonce` per the [spec](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/).

I saw [one answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214480/post-comments-using-wp-rest-api-v2-in-wordpress/249699) suggest adding this filter: `add_filter( 'filter_rest_allow_anonymous_comments', '__return_true' );`

I keep getting the same 401 response. If I post using basic auth, it works, nonces aren't.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

`add_filter( 'filter_rest_allow_anonymous_comments', '__return_true' );`

should be:

`add_filter( 'rest_allow_anonymous_comments', '__return_true' );`

I found it by looking for the filter itself and saw that it was different than in the original answer.