# Wordpress REST API rest_comment_invalid_author Sorry, you are not allowed to edit 'author' for comments

Tags: rest-api

I'm fairly new to Wordpress REST API, but I have an Angular application which needs to take user's input and then create a comment anonymously. To start off, we can get rid of the [`rest_comment_login_required`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/249699/220035) error message by modifying the Wordpress REST API function located in `wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-comments-controller.php` file. The following line allows anonymous commenting:

```
$allow_anonymous = apply_filters( 'rest_allow_anonymous_comments', true, $request );
```

In my Wordpress REST API, sending a `GET` request to `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1` returns:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "root",
    "url": "http://localhost/wordpress",
    "description": "",
    "link": "http://localhost/wordpress/author/root/",
    "slug": "root",
    "avatar_urls": {
        "24": "http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/d11662ae04f559ce691c5b1b4ff906f7?s=24&d=mm&r=g",
        "48": "http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/d11662ae04f559ce691c5b1b4ff906f7?s=48&d=mm&r=g",
        "96": "http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/d11662ae04f559ce691c5b1b4ff906f7?s=96&d=mm&r=g"
    },
    "meta": [ ],
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                    "href": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
            }
    ],
    "collection": [
        {
            "href": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/users"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I only have one user currently in my database, who is called `root`.

If I simulate a request to the API with Postman and send a `POST` request to `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/comments` while supplying a raw JSON body thata looks like

```
{
    "content": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry",
    "date": "2021-08-04T22:24:09",
    "post": 1,
    "author": 1,
    "author_name": "root",
    "author_url": "http://localhost/wordpress"
}
```

then I get an error

```
{
    "code": "rest_comment_invalid_author",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to edit 'author' for comments.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

What is the meaning of this error and how do I fix this?

Comment: you should never modify WordPress core files, the `apply_filters` call means that it's passing the value to that filter giving you the opportunity to add your own filter in a plugin or theme, so modifying or commenting out that file is unnecessary, and would normally be flagged as a security breach by security plugins and software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are sending unauthenticated anonymous requests, but still specifying an author. If what you were trying to do worked then it would be possible to impersonate any person on your site in a comment by specifying their author ID when creating the request.

With this in mind, the error message is quite clear.

Here you're trying to edit the `author` property by setting it to `1`:

```json
    "author": 1,
```

And here the REST API is seeing this and saying *No, you can't do that, you don't have permission*:

```json
    "code": "rest_comment_invalid_author",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to edit 'author' for comments.",
```

Anonymous logged out requests cannot edit other users comments or impersonate them.

So to fix this, either remove the author ID, **or** send an authenticated request, authenticated with that same user, or an administrator.

---

Additionally, the line you commented out was a filter:

```php
$allow_anonymous = apply_filters( 'rest_allow_anonymous_comments', true, $request );
```

Instead of modifying WordPres files, instead hook into the filter to return `true` in a theme or plugin:

```php
add_filter( 'rest_allow_anonymous_comments', '__return_true' );
```

or

```php
add_filter( 'rest_allow_anonymous_comments', '__return_false' );
```